# use java variable in jstl sql:query

Tags: java, jsp, jstl

Struggling with some code which works perfectly well in one jsp but not another.

Uses a java variable which is always set correctly.

```
<%
chosen4 = assetselected;
System.out.println("chosen4 value=" + chosen4);
%>
```

There is a button on my page which does a refresh which successfully runs -

```
<%
String assetselected = request.getParameter("comparedid")
%>
```

Then I attempt to use the variable in a sql:query

```
<sql:query var="queryresults" dataSource="jdbc/database">
select 
name
from asset 
where 
and asset.alerton = 1
and asset.id like <%=chosen4%>
```

Have to use like instead of = as otherwise the query never returns anything (in the working jsp).

I now this is not the best code in the world but I am at a loss as to why like <%=chosen4%> works perfectly in one jsp and not the other.

Regards
Ralph

Comment: Please Google "Implicit EL objects" and "SQL injection"

Answer (score 1):

First set variable of `comparedid` in jsp by

```
<c:set var = "empId" value =${param.comparedid} />
```

Then sql query like

```
<sql:query var="queryresults" dataSource="jdbc/database">
        select name from asset where asset.alerton = 1 and asset.id=?
        <sql:param value = "${empId}" />
</sql:query>
```

> Note: You will have to use this tag `<%@ taglib uri =
>   "http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix = "c"%>` on the top of jsp
>   page and add jstl dependency on pom.xml

Comment: Thanks for all replies, I eventually added a button to force a page refresh but it appears try blocks (to check if the button was pushed) do not support multiple line sql statements so I have had to abandon this approach.